# Droid 9-patch Splash is black on some devices

Tags: android, splash-screen

I'm using a 9-patch to place a logo on the splash screen. This works on most test devices, as well as on simulators, but on one particular device – an SM-T230 – it shows up like this:

[Image of splash screen where all space under the logo is turned black (Logo is deliberately blurred)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivOzb.png)

I created the 9-patch for all DPIs (LDPI, HDPI, ...).

It does appear to be scaling it; its size (in raw pixels) is about halfway between the size of the MDPI and HDPI images.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have the same issue. Have you any progress with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I solved this by adding an extra pixel margin around the content of the image.